# How to get a Flask-Login form value from another route

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a Flask login form and route that successfully work. Now i want to get the form value and query the database based on it from another route but it returns None.

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    user_id= StringField('user_id',validators = [DataRequired()])
    password= PasswordField('Password', validators = [DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

Now i want to get the user_id of the login-form from the below user_data route

```
@app.route('/user_data', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def user_data():
    user_id= request.form.get('user_id')
    print(user_id)
    pass
    return render_template('user_data.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use session to store current user in your login route, and get current user from session in your userdata route:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    session['username'] = request.form['username']
    ..

@app.route('/user_data', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def user_data():
    user_id= session['username']
    return render_template('user_data.html')
```

or something like this

```
from flask_login import current_user
@app.route('/user_data', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def user_data():
    user = current_user
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i can get the value.